# sufficient condition for invertibility of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following claim:

Let $A$ be 3 by 3 matrix. If there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $(I-A)^k = 0$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, then $A$ is invertible.

My attempt was to take the determinant of both sides of $(I-A)^k = 0$ so that I get det$(I-A)=0$, but then I cannot really see why this implies $A$ is invertible.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3):

Expand $(I-A)^k$:
$$
0=(I-A)^k=\sum_{m=0}^{k}(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}A^m=
I-A\sum_{m=1}^{k}(-1)^{m-1}\binom{k}{m}A^{m-1}
$$
so
$$
A\sum_{m=1}^{k}(-1)^{m-1}\binom{k}{m}A^{m-1}=I
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $C = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (I-A)^j$.  Notice that $C(I-A) = \sum_{j=1}^{k} (I-A)^j = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (I-A)^j = C-I$.  Hence $CA = I$.

Answer (score 1):

By the hypothesis $B=A-I$ is nilpotent so it's similar to strictly upper triangle matrix so $A$ is similar to a triangle matrix with $1$ on the diagonal. Conclude.